# How to count the visible number of lines of text in a text box on an MS Access form

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, textbox

OK, here's what I am trying to achieve. I have an MS Access 2016 DB with a form on it - one of the fields is a text field (max 255 chars), that users can enter "notes", by date.

The form is a continuous form, and there are a LOT of notes. And as most notes are only a single sentence, not the full 255 chars, to save screen space, the text box is sized to only allow show two lines of text (users can double click on the note to see the full text in the rare instances that the text is up to 255 chars).

The problem with this approach is that it is not always clear if a note goes beyond the two lines.

So I am trying to find a way to tell how many lines of text the note uses in the text box, and then I'll highlight the text box if this is the case.

Note what I am talking about here is text wrapping within a text box, not (necessarily) text with line breaks (although there may be line breaks also). Given the wrapping changes dependent upon the text (eg long words will "wrap early" to a new line), so using a simple char count doesn't work, even with a monospace  font.

I have searched a lot online and found nothing, except a ref to a possible solution here:
http://www.lebans.com/textwidth-height.htm

But the download is an old Access file type I can no longer open.

Does anyone have any ideas (except for a form redesign - which is my last option hopefully!)

Comment: The easy method is to make the height of the textbox = (n + 0.5) lines. This way the user can at once see if the text extends beyond n lines.

Comment: @Gustav - accepted, and this might be my last ditch solution - but this then increases the size of my text box, which I am trying to avoid!

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of lines in a string, or text box, you can use this expression:

```
UBound(Split(str, vbCrLf))
```

So

```
UBound(Split([textBoxName], vbCrLf))
```

Comment: @ Albert From my quick test that does not work - it shows the correct number of lines for text that has a manually entered line break, but not for text where the text is simply "wrapped" to the next line in the text box (ie there is no vbCrLf, but the total text is longer than the width of the text box so it wraps onto the next line)

Comment: You are correct - I assumed you wanted to count lines - not lines due to word wrap. Counting lines due to word wrap is a very different problem.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have come up with a "solution" to this - it's neither neat nor fast, but it appears to work in my situation. I have posted the VBA code for anyone for whom it might interest.

This function is then used on a continuous form's textbox conditional highlighting, so I can highlight those instances where the text has wrapped beyond "n" lines (in my case, two lines)

FYI it's only partially tested, with no error handling!

```
' Returns TRUE if the text in a textbox wraps/breaks beyond the number of visible lines in the text box (before scrolling)
' THIS ONLY WORKS FOR MONOSPACE FONTS IN A TEXTBOX WHERE WE KNOW THE WidthInMonospaceCharacters
' WidthInMonospaceCharacters = number of MONOSPACE characters to EXACTLY fill one line in your text box (needs to be counted manually
' VisibleLinesInTextBox = number of lines your text box shows on screen (without scrolling)

Function UnseenLinesInTextBox(YourText As String, WidthInMonospaceCharacters As Long, VisibleLinesInTextBox As Long) As Boolean

Dim LineBreakTexts() As String
Dim CleanText As String
Dim LineCount As Long
Dim LineBreaks As Long
Dim i As Long

'   Doesn't matter if we can't see invisible end spaces/line breaks, so lose them
'   NB advise cleaning text whenver data updated then no need to run this line
    CleanText = ClearEndSpacesAndLineBreaks(YourText)

'   Check for any line breaks
    LineBreakTexts = Split(CleanText, vbCrLf)

'   Too many line breaks means we can't be all in the textbox, so report and GTFOOD
    LineBreaks = UBound(LineBreakTexts)
    If LineBreaks >= VisibleLinesInTextBox Then
        UnseenLinesInTextBox = True
        GoTo CleanExit
    End If

'   No line breaks, and text too short to wrap, so exit
    If LineBreaks = 0 And Len(CleanText) <= WidthInMonospaceCharacters Then GoTo CleanExit

'   Loop thorough the line break text, and check word wrapping for each
    For i = 0 To LineBreaks

        LineCount = LineCount + CountWrappedLines(LineBreakTexts(i), WidthInMonospaceCharacters, VisibleLinesInTextBox)

        If LineCount > VisibleLinesInTextBox Then
            UnseenLinesInTextBox = True
            GoTo CleanExit
        End If

    Next i

CleanExit:
    Erase LineBreakTexts


End Function

' Add BugOutLineCount if we are using this simply to see if we are exceeding X number of lines in a textbox
' Put this number of lines here (eg if we have a two line text box, enter 2)
Function CountWrappedLines(YourText As String, WidthInMonospaceCharacters As Long, Optional BugOutLineCount As Long) As Long

Dim SpaceBreakTexts() As String
Dim LineCount As Long, RollingCount As Long, SpaceBreaks As Long, i As Long
Dim WidthAdjust As Long
Dim CheckBugOut As Boolean
Dim tmpLng1 As Long, tmpLng2 As Long

    If BugOutLineCount > 0 Then CheckBugOut = True

'   Check for space breaks
    SpaceBreakTexts = Split(YourText, " ")
    SpaceBreaks = UBound(SpaceBreakTexts)

    If SpaceBreaks = 0 Then

'       No spaces, so text will wrap simply based on the number of characters per line
        CountWrappedLines = NoSpacesWrap(YourText, WidthInMonospaceCharacters)
        GoTo CleanExit

    End If

'   Need to count the wrapped line breaks manually
'   We must start with at least one line!
    LineCount = 1

    For i = 0 To SpaceBreaks

        tmpLng1 = Len(SpaceBreakTexts(i))

        If i = 0 Then
'           Do not count spaces in the first word...
            RollingCount = RollingCount + tmpLng1
        Else
'           ... but add spaces to the count for the next texts
            RollingCount = 1 + RollingCount + tmpLng1
        End If

'       Need this adjustment as wrapping works slightly differently between mid and
'       end of text
        If i = SpaceBreaks Then
            WidthAdjust = WidthInMonospaceCharacters
        Else
            WidthAdjust = WidthInMonospaceCharacters - 1
        End If

'       Check when we get a wrapped line
        If RollingCount > WidthAdjust Then

'           Check the the length of the word itself doesn't warp over more than one line
            If tmpLng1 > WidthInMonospaceCharacters Then
                tmpLng2 = NoSpacesWrap(SpaceBreakTexts(i), WidthInMonospaceCharacters)
                If i <> 0 Then
                    LineCount = LineCount + tmpLng2
                Else
                    LineCount = tmpLng2
                End If
'               As we have wrapped, then we already have a word on the next line to count in the rolling count
                RollingCount = tmpLng1 - ((tmpLng2 - 1) * WidthInMonospaceCharacters)
            Else
'               New line reached
                LineCount = LineCount + 1
'               As we have wrapped, then we already have a word on the next line to count in the rolling count
                RollingCount = Len(SpaceBreakTexts(i))
            End If

        End If

        If CheckBugOut Then If LineCount > BugOutLineCount Then Exit For

    Next i

CountWrappedLines = LineCount

CleanExit:
    Erase SpaceBreakTexts


End Function

' Work out how many lines text will wrap if it has NO spaces
Function NoSpacesWrap(YourText As String, WidthInMonospaceCharacters) As Long

Dim WordLines As Double
Dim MyInt As Integer

    WordLines = (Len(YourText) / WidthInMonospaceCharacters)
    MyInt = Int(WordLines)

'   Line(s) are exact width we are looking at
    If WordLines - MyInt = 0 Then
        NoSpacesWrap = MyInt
    Else
        NoSpacesWrap = MyInt + 1
    End If

End Function

Function ClearEndSpacesAndLineBreaks(YourText As String) As String

Dim str As String
Dim CurrentLength As Long

str = YourText

'   Need to loop this in case we have a string of line breaks and spaces invisibly at end of text
    Do

        CurrentLength = Len(str)

    '   Clear end spaces
        str = RTrim(str)

    '   Clear end line break(s) whihc are TWO characters long
        Do
            If Right(str, 2) <> vbCrLf Then Exit Do
            str = Left(str, Len(str) - 2)
        Loop

        If Len(str) = CurrentLength Then Exit Do

    Loop

ClearEndSpacesAndLineBreaks = str

End Function
```

Do please provide any feedback and comments!